# AWS batch job failing with python time.sleep() over 70 seconds

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sleep, aws-batch

Python 3.8.10 running in aws batch.

When the batch job gets to here:

`time.sleep(360)`

The batch job fails. No AWS exception is provided in CloudWatch.

But if I use `time.sleep(70)`, the batch job runs to success. I've identified 70 seconds as a sweet spot, `time.sleep(80)` fails.

The program runs without a hitch locally, and in a Jenkins pipeline.

Any idea why this is occurring, and how to come around it?

Comment: do you have a timeout set on your job when you submit it?

Comment: or on the job definition?

Comment: This was it.  The execution timeout was set to 60 seconds in the console. I completely missed that. Thank-you!